# Saving large, multidimensional forms with ajax when a link is clicked

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

I have a lot of trouble trying to set up an ajax call in my online shop.

The whole order system is quite big. Collections are divided into categories and categories are divided into products. Products are divided into three sizes: S, M and L.

For every collection, order form looks like this (simplified) :

```
echo '<form name="input" action="processing.php" method="POST">';

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    foreach ($productids as $productid) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="input['.$productid.'][s]" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="input['.$productid.'][m]" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="input['.$productid.'][l]" />';
    }
}

echo '</form>';
```

Setting up the form like this is very convenient because all the input is in $_POST['input'] array.

On the top of the page, there are several links to different collections. When the user clicks a link, I want to pass all data of the current collection's input fields via ajax to a php file in order to save it to database.

Markup of a link:

```
<a href="index.php?action=order&collection=2" class="changecoll">Collection 2</a>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How to pass such a lot of inputs to processing.php via an jquery.ajax call? What to put in the data parameter?
2. Is triggering an jquery.ajax call when a link is clicked the right approach to this problem?

Comment: If a lot of data, I would send via JSON. Sending jQuery.ajax upon click event (I assume a SUBMIT button or some such) is also what I would do. Seems like you are on the right track to me.

Comment: [This](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin will serialize your form and do an ajax request. You will of course need to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably do something like:

PHP:

```
echo '<form name="input" action="processing.php" method="POST">';

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    foreach ($productids as $productid) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="input_'. $productid .'_s" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="input_'. $productid .'_m" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="input_'. $productid .'_l" />';
    }
}

echo '</form>';
```

HTML/JS:

```
<a href="index.php?action=order&collection=2" class="changecoll">Collection 2</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $(".changecoll").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {};

        $("input[name^='input']").each(function(i, el) {
            var tmp = el.split("_");
            data[tmp[1] +"_" + tmp[2]] = $(el).val();
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save.php",
            data: {
                input: JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            success: function() {
                document.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
            }
        });
    });
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in the example that you gave, you'll want to escape single quotes around s, m and l as that'll result in an error.

For what purpose would you be saving everything? If it's so the user can revisit it, is it really worth saving without them explicitly requesting?

The data parameter in jQuery.ajax() is a simple one, just give your form an id, then grab the data like so

```
var formData = $('form#formId').serialize();
```

Now in your ajax call, just pass formData to data.

I am however still curious about what exactly these forms hold, and why you need to save it.